# How to make FileUpload control upload file right after clicking 'Browse'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Untill now, I've been using 2 controls (FileUpload and additional button).
After file was chosen in a fileUpload control, user had to accept his choice by pressing save button.

Here's button's code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/file.jpg"));
            Label1.Text = Server.MapPath("~/file.jpg");
            Image1.ImageUrl = "file.jpg";
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering whether there is a way to avoid using that button, so the FileUpload control's button would do the additional button's job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FileUpload` control renders an `<input type="file>` in the browser. You can use the javascript [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onchange) event to trigger the upload.

First make sure you have a `load` event handler registered in the `body` of your page:

```
<body onload="body_onload()">
```

And add this code inside your event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function body_onload()
    {
        ...

        $get('<%=FileUpload.ClientID%>').onchange = function() { 
            $get('<%=this.Page.Form.ClientID%>').submit(); 
        };
    }
</script>
```

---

Or to do this using pure jQuery, place this in the `head` of your page (if you don't already have jQuery included):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then use this code to bind to the event (replace `#fileUpload1` and `#form1` with the id's of your `FileUpload` and `Form` elements, respectively):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fileUpload1").change(function() {
            $("#form1").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```